# Open URL as File

Tags: macos, filesystem, url

If I go to an application and open a file, such as using Cmd-O, is there some way to enter a URL, so that I can open a file directly from the web?

For example, in a graphics application, I would like to open an image file directly from the URL without having first to save it from the browser.

I know I can point to a local path using Cmd-G.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no generic way of doing that in every application on macOS.

Some specific applications provide a way of opening a URL - for example VLC Player allows you to open a URL and play a video directly from the web.